# Prove directly from the definition that $({1\over2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})_n $ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Prove directly from the definition that $({1\over2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})_n$ is cauchy
I know from the definition of Cauchy that |$x_n$-$x_m$|< ϵ but how do you do this with |$\frac{1}{2^n}- \frac{1}{2^m}$|

what I've tried:
if $n\gt m$ then
$$ |\frac{1}{2^n}- \frac{1}{2^m}| \le |\frac{2^m-2^n}{2^n2^m}| \le |\frac{2^m +2^n}{2^{n+m}}| \le \frac{2^n+2^n}{2^{2n}}= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}     \le \frac{1}{2^{N-1}} \le \epsilon   $$
and rearrange to get N $ \ge 1+ \frac{ln(\epsilon)}{ln(2)}$
is this correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: It should be $N\geq 1 - \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2)}$.

Comment: can you show how please? @kingW3

Comment: @kingW3 Actually, the equality holds.

Comment: Yeah, haven't had my coffe yet...deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$.  Then, we have for any $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|S_n-S_m\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=\min(m,n)+1}^{\max(m.n)}\frac{1}{2^k}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{2^{\min(n,m)}}-\frac{1}{2^{\max(m,n)}}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{2^{\min(n,m)-1}}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\min(n,m)>1-\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(2)}$

Comment: this really helped, thanks so much!

Comment: @kenny Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Mark.Kindly check my post below. Is it correct? I am a bit suspicious, but cannot find a mistake.Thanks.

Comment: @Kenny Oh and please feel free to up vote and accept and answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the series satisfies the Cauchy condition you have to estimate, for $n,p\in\mathbb{N}$, the difference
$$
\sum_{j=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{2^j}  = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}\right) < \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\,.
$$
Given $\varepsilon > 0$, it is enough to choose $N > 1 - \log_2\varepsilon$ so that
$$
\sum_{j=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{2^j} < \varepsilon
\qquad
\forall n> N, \ p\in\mathbb{N}. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

$S_m,S_n $ are the partial sums in the problem:

$|S_n - S_m| =|1/2^n -1/2^m|;$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given .

Choose $N_0$ such that $N_0 \gt 2 (1/\epsilon)$.
(Archimedes)

Then:

For $m,n \gt N_0 :$

$|S_n-S_m| = |1/2^n-1/2^m| \lt $

$|1/2^n|+|1/2^m| \lt 1/n +1/m \lt$

$2/N_0 \lt \epsilon.$

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark.

Comment: You're welcome!